# Fetch inside of map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, post, socrata

I am trying to fetch data from a Socrata API and then post it to my own database.  When I run the function in node, I get the error "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined"

I am totally lost, and am wondering how to pull this off.  I have been googling for the past four hours, and can't find anything.

My code:

```
const apiURL = "https://ftbserver.herokuapp.com/npos"
const soda = require('soda-js');

var consumer = new soda.Consumer('data.colorado.gov');

let stuff

consumer.query()
    .withDataset('p3jp-z4tq')
    .limit(2)
    .where({ principalcity: 'Denver' })
    // .order('namelast')
    .getRows()
    .on('success', function (rows) {
        rows.map((nposNew) => {
            let data = {
                fein: nposNew.fein,
                name: nposNew.name,
                revenuetotal: nposNew.revenuetotal,
                expensestotal: nposNew.expensestotal
            }
            fetch(apiURL, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }),
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    showSuccess(response.message)
                    setTimeout(() => (removeMsg()), 4000);
                })
                .catch(console.error);
    }) 
})
    .on('error', function (error) { console.error(error); });
// console.log(stuff);

// console.log(npost);
```

Comment: `When I run the function in node`  yes, fetch is not part of node.   But there is a small polyfill you could use -> `https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch`

Comment: I have used Fetch before, but I have never had to install it as a package

Comment: Well `fetch` is just not part of `node.js`,  maybe you've used it before within browsers, as it's part of modern browsers.

Comment: Oooooohhhhhhhhhhhhhh.  Thanks for clearing that up.  That makes so much sense.